# comper div A to div B height & only if A is higher add height to div b

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to compare 2 divs height and just in case div A is higher add height to div B ( I have a few divs that some of the height is not heeded any adjustment
and im trying to achieve it using js but any other idea is as good

```
 `<div class="row">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="col-md-1 Acomp">
            <button class="btn">If this on is higher Make this one equal  </button >
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 Acomp">
            <p>most of the time this  one height if higher no need to adjust  </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`


       var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".Acomp"),
            heights = [];
        console.log(heights);
        [].forEach.call(elements,
            function(each) {
                heights[heights.length] = getComputedStyle(each, null).getPropertyValue("height");
            });

        heights.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a);
            newFunction(a, b);
        }));

        function newFunction(a, b) {
            if (a < b) {
                [].forEach.call(elements,
                    function(each) {
                        each.style.height = heights[0];
                    }); }; }

`
```

Comment: What problems did you have?

Comment: not working & I never get to   if (a < b) never get to in breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making the problem more complex than it really is.

Here's my solution for **two div**s:

```js
/* ------------THE FIRST SOLUTION: BEGIN------------ */
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".Acomp")

if (elements[1].clientHeight < elements[0].clientHeight) {
  elements[1].style.height = elements[0].clientHeight + "px"
}
/* -------------THE FIRST SOLUTION: END------------- */



// here're two additional functions - not nicely written, but show that
// you don't just add a number to height, because that's a string
document.getElementsByClassName('addHeightB')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  elements[1].style.height = parseInt(elements[1].style.height, 10) + 30 + "px"
})

document.getElementsByClassName('subtractHeightB')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  elements[1].style.height = parseInt(elements[1].style.height, 10) - 30 + "px"
})

// here's the reset function for the first button
document.getElementsByClassName('setHeightToA')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  elements[1].style.height = elements[0].clientHeight + "px"
})
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="col-md-1 Acomp">
      <button class="btn setHeightToA">If this on is higher Make this one equal  </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 Acomp" style="background-color: gray; color: white;">
      <p>most of the time this one height if higher no need to adjust </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn addHeightB">Add 30px height to B</button>
<button class="btn subtractHeightB">Subtract 30px height from B</button>
```

Here's the solution for **n div**s:

(actually two solutions)

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".Acomp")

let heights = []

for (let element of Object.values(elements)) {
  heights.push(element.clientHeight)
}

/* ------------THE SECOND SOLUTION: BEGIN----------- */
// if the first element is the highest, then all elements should have the same height
if (elements[0].clientHeight === Math.max.apply(null, heights)) {
  for (let element of Object.values(elements)) {
    element.style.height = elements[0].clientHeight + "px"
  }
}
/* -------------THE SECOND SOLUTION: END------------ */

/* ------------THE THIRD SOLUTION: BEGIN------------ */
// make all elements as high as the highest
heights = heights.sort().reverse()

for (let element of Object.values(elements)) {
  element.style.height = heights[0] + "px"
}
/* -------------THE THIRD SOLUTION: END------------- */

/* ------------THE THIRD B SOLUTION: BEGIN------------ */
// make all elements as high as the highest
const maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights)

for (let element of Object.values(elements)) {
  element.style.height = maxHeight + "px"
}
/* -------------THE THIRD B SOLUTION: END------------- */
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="col-md-1 Acomp">
      <button class="btn setHeightToA">If this on is higher Make this one equal  </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 Acomp" style="background-color: gray; color: white;">
      <p>most of the time this one height if higher no need to adjust </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn addHeightB">Add 30px height to B</button>
<button class="btn subtractHeightB">Subtract 30px height from B</button>
```

Comment: I really  impress by your work but none was working as it should https://jsfiddle.net/5dq96xmc/

Comment: I’ll have a look at your fiddle :)

Comment: This works: https://jsfiddle.net/mukagergely/b0hq7rs3/17/ If you didn't want to work like this (making everything equal height), please elaborate your problem more. If you only want it to work if the first div is the tallest, then it's just an if-else to limit functionality.